# r match filenames in two folders and perform code

Tags: r, file, directory, match

I have 2 folders with text files: Aba with 90 files and Baa with 50 files. I have a piece of code where I open files with same names from two folders and perform operation.

```
dna_no= read.table("/home/Documents/Baa/112.txt",skip=1, header=TRUE, sep="\t", fill=FALSE)
sim = read.table("/home/Documents/Data/Aba/112.txt",header=FALSE, sep="\t")
```

then I want to perform code on contents of files:

Select rows from sim where 1st column of dna_no matches 1st column sim:

```
sm_dna=  sim[which(dna_no[,1]%in%sim[,1]),]
sim_nn17 = cbind(sm_dna[,1],sm_dna[,4:6]
```

etc.

Now I want to do this in one go for all files in Baa find file with the same name from Aba and do the above operation.

I'm using list.files:

```
filenames= list.files("/home/Documents/Baa/", full.names=TRUE)

file_sim= list.files("/home/Documents/Data/Aba/",full.names=TRUE)

ldf <- lapply(filenames, function(x) read.table(x,skip=1))
tcf <- lapply(file_sim, function(z) read.table(z,colClasses = c(rep("numeric", 6), rep("NULL", 1)),header=FALSE, sep="\t"))
```

so now I need to find ldf[i] that is same in tcf [i] , i.e. files with the same names (e.g. 112 file names are all numeric) and I cannot figure out how to do it as list.files seems not to safe files names.

and then perform code for each of the files.

```
myFun <- function(filenames){
```

same operation described above for each file:

```
sm_dna=  ..

sim_nn17 =..

...}
```

I'm not sure how does the code change here as well?
would it be possible do this without loop?

the code works fine for separate files but not for a batch of files in folder.

many thanks for help!

Comment: `list.files` returns a vector of file names, i.e. an object of 1 dimension. Why do you have the `[,1]` bit in `filenames[,1] %in% file_sim[,1]` ? I would imagine that causes an error

Comment: @arvi1000 sorry see my updated question. that was just an example. I basically need to apply code designed for single files for the whole batch of files in folder..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have you two distinct questions here, really.

1. Find matching list items
2. Execute some operations on a series of files without a for-loop

The first thing is pretty simple. Here's a reproducible example, but you could use two lists of filenames from calls to `list.files` or anything here

```
# here are two random vectors of letters
set.seed(1)
vec1 <- letters[sample(1:26, 5)]
vec2 <- letters[sample(1:26, 15)]

# > vec1
# [1] "g" "j" "n" "u" "e"
# > vec2
# [1] "x" "z" "p" "o" "b" "e" "d" "n" "g" "s" "h" "k" "q" "u" "j"

# here are the matching ones 
intersect(vec1, vec2)
# [1] "g" "j" "n" "u" "e"
```

The second thing is simple too: read in two files of the same name from different locations, perform some operations:

```
my_func <- function(filename) {

  # get files with same name from two dirs
  dna_no <- read.table(paste0('/home/Documents/Baa/', filename))
  sim <- read.table(paste0('/home/Documents/Data/Aba/', filename))

  # do other stuff...
}
```

Putting these together you can do something like:

```
filenames <- list.files("/home/Documents/Baa/")
file_sim <- list.files("/home/Documents/Data/Aba/")

lapply(intersect(filenames, file_sim), my_func)
```

Comment: Thank you for 'intersect' and paste0. I have learned new things. When I use this however it returns list()..is this because I need to define multiple return?

Comment: lapply always returns a list. What structure are you looking for? Have you tried using sapply or unlist(lapply(...)) ?

Comment: unlist(lapply()) shows me "NULL". and sapply shows me "named list()"..what I mean it is just literally "list()" nothing else. how do i see results in this list()? as it seems zero right now

Comment: Maybe `intersect` is returning null bc there are no items in common between the two lists. You haven't posted your data or a reproducible example, though, so this it's hard to help further. Try to post a reproducible example

Comment: I just see now the mistake. I need to intersect file names,.i.e.  not contents as the contents do not have anything in common. 'dna_no' and 'sim' have to be same,in the example '112.txt'. the contents of folders have same names. thanks for advice i will post an example of my code.

Comment: Exactly - intersect the two lists of file names

Comment: So it should work. I don't know why it doesn't work. I'll edit my question and provide my code and example of files..could you please pin point whats wrong?